# How can I write a commmand in R that groups by multiple critera?

Tags: r, if-statement

I am looking for a function where I can classify my data into five different industries given their SIC code

```
Permno  SIC  Industry
1       854 
2       977 
3       549 
4       1231    
5       3295    
6       2000    
7       1539    
8       2549    
9       3950    
10      4758    
11      4290    
12      5498    
13      5248    
14      142 
15      3209    
16      2759    
17      4859    
18      2569    
19      739 
20      4529
```

It could be that all SICS between 100-200 and 400-700 should be in Industry 1, all SICs between 300-350 and 980-1020 should be in Industry 2 etc.

So in short - an 'If = or' function where I could list all the SICs that could match a given industry
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new column with the filters by number:

For example:

```
data$Group <- 0
data[data$SCIS < 1000, data$Group == 1]
data[data$SCIS >= 1000,  data$Group == 2 ]
```

Comment: Thanks;
I just edited my question as I realized my question was not very precise .. Is this method suitable if I want to list a range of SICs that could be classified into e.g. industry 1?
E.g.

data$Group <- 0 %>%
data[data$SCIS = 500, data$Group == 1]
data[data$SCIS = 200, data$Group == 1]

Answer (score 0):

`floor` the value after dividing the `SIC` value by 1000.

```
df$Industry <- floor(df$SIC/1000) + 1
df

#   Permno  SIC Industry
#1       1  854        1
#2       2  977        1
#3       3  549        1
#4       4 1231        2
#5       5 3295        4
#6       6 2000        3
#7       7 1539        2
#8       8 2549        3
#9       9 3950        4
#10     10 4758        5
#11     11 4290        5
#12     12 5498        6
#13     13 5248        6
#14     14  142        1
#15     15 3209        4
#16     16 2759        3
#17     17 4859        5
#18     18 2569        3
#19     19  739        1
#20     20 4529        5
```

---

If there is no way to programmatically define groups you may need to individually define the ranges. It is convenient to do this with `case_when` in `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Industry = case_when(between(SIC, 100, 200) | between(SIC, 400, 700) ~ 'Industry 1', 
                              between(SIC, 300, 350) | between(SIC, 980, 1020) ~ 'Industry 2'))
```

Comment: Hi Ronak,
Sorry my question was not very precise to begin with - I have clarified it a bit now.
I need a code which can handle an if-function where multiple criteria could match ..

E.g. If I want to classify the exact SICs = 500, 1500 or 2700 into "Industry 1", how would I do this?

Comment: @FredrikClement See my updated answer with `case_when`.

Comment: Hi Ronak - I tried this but it just assigned all my observations into 'Industry 1' ?

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. Can you provide sample of your data in a reproducible format using `dput` and show corresponding expected output for it?

Comment: My computer just seems running as if it works in a loop ... I managed to solve it using the above method however, thanks for your help, Ronak!